# ¿Qué criterio siguen ustedes al manejar las colas de revisión para votos de cierre y reapertura?

Tags: discusión, votos-de-cierre, votos-de-reapertura

Pregunto porque llevo rato que me da la impresión que solo el primer voto de cierre o reapertura es el que cuenta en realidad.  Una vez que eso pasa y que la pregunta se encuentra en las colas de revisión, parece casi automático que la pregunta o se cierra o se abre según la clase de cola de revisión en la que se encuentre.

De forma similar, a veces noto preguntas puestas en espera (con razón) que después son editadas de forma menor, y que no mejoran en nada la pregunta. Pero, por el simple hecho de haber sido editadas, la pregunta aparece en la cola de revisión como candidato para ser reabierto, y muy a menudo termina por ser reabierto. Y aunque la pregunta merece permanecer cerrada, ya no puedo votar una segunda vez...

¿Han notado algo similar? ¿Cómo deciden ustedes cómo votar en esas colas de revisión?

¿O será que algunos votan por votar sin mirar? ¿Será eso lo que explica que [esta pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1250/live-usb-kali-linux-mac-probind-edd) acabó siendo migrada al sitio meta de forma inexplicable????  ¿O sea que, uno se equivocó, y luego 4 votaron sin prestar atención?

¿Y si creen que es un problema, hay algo que se pueda hacer para corregir este patrón?

En lo personal, yo evito votar cuando se trate de temas que no entiendo bien. Para eso está el botón `Omitir`.

Comment: Interesantísima reflexión con la que estoy muy de acuerdo y que hago extensiva a los votos: cuando una publicación tiene votos, suelen "caerle" muchos más; si no los tiene, suele quedarse a cero. Creo que esto tiene que ver con la pereza: si alguien dijo esto, debe estar en lo cierto, por tanto repito su acción sin mayor debate interno. Lo que se me ocurre es añadir comentarios para hacer explícito tu punto de vista diferente: si todos votan por cerrar y no te parece correcto, ¡dilo! Tu comentario puede hacer que el resto de gente vea un punto de vista diferente y se replantee su postura.

Comment: El primer paso a la solución serian los [audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work), pero... estando como estamos: ¿quien audita los audits?

Comment: @fedorqui estoy muy de acuerdo, y lo hago extensivo a los comentarios tambien (los upvotes sobre los comentarios ;p). Estamos en una crisis de: **lo hago porque puedo (tengo el poder de hacerlo), sin medir las consecuencias**. Es decir que estamos en la infancia y necesitamos madurar como comunidad.

Comment: He visto varias preguntas con la calidad esperada para el sitio cerradas por personas que ni siquiera participan en las etiquetas indicadas. Esto me parece que es resultado de lo que indicas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Creo que cada cual utiliza un criterio, pero que hay uno que resulta pernicioso para el sitio:

- El que busca medallas sin importarle demasiado lo que está revisando.

Dada esta situación podemos hacer dos cosas:

- <s>Esperar a que ganen las medallas</s> → no me gusta, pues durante este tiempo siempre habrá problemas; además, siempre llegará nueva gente que no tenga esas medallas y corra por conseguirlas.
- Poner [auditorías](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121/209901) → me gusta pues ayudará a que la gente se tome las revisiones con más calma y sensatez.

Mientras tanto, debemos recordar que...

#### No hay que sentirse mal por apretar el botón Omitir:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nadie sabe de todo, así que es mejor dejar que quien sepa se encargue de algo si nosotros no nos consideramos capacitados para ello.

Comment: A mí también me parece la opción más sensata. Si bien todos podemos equivocarnos en algún caso hay diferencias entre eso y la búsqueda de medallas. Bien es cierto que requiere algo más de trabajo de administración pero no creo que se vaya a caer el portal por añadir esa característica.

Comment: Lo de las medallas en este caso causa más problemas que beneficios. Cuando las colas estaban llenas en el sitio inglés hacía falta incentivar su uso, no es el caso aquí.

Comment: Creo que tienes razón, hay personas que parecen tener una obsesión con reportar por reportar, o cerrar por cerrar las cosas, y en muchos casos ni saben el porque.

Answer (score 6):

No debería importarte cómo revisan los demás, intenta revisar con lo que te parezca, no te dejes llevar por los demás votos. Si se te acaban los votos podrías reportarla a un moderador.

Mis criterios para revisar los votos de cierre, son algo como esto:

- Algunas veces es válido preguntar sin código, otras veces no.
- Las preguntas que solo tienen el código deben cerrarse, ya que no explica el contexto.
- Las de baja calidad, las que están en inglés también. Si son traducidas incluso puede no ser válida y debe cerrarse.
- Si es posible que el usuario mejore su pregunta o respuesta, dejar un comentario.
- Si no hay motivos para cerrarla, dejarla abierta, si no se sabe si es válida o no, mejor omitir.