# ¿Cómo podemos sugerir que las ediciones sean más sustanciales en la cola de "ediciones sugeridas"?

Tags: discusión, ediciones-sugeridas, revisiones

Soy asiduo de las [colas de revisión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review). En ellas observo grandes aportaciones por parte de mucha gente: unos sugieren mejoras, otros acaban de llegar y publican sus primeras preguntas o respuestas, etc. Es, en fin, un lugar donde ver cómo la comunidad va creciendo y confiando en sus miembros.

Centrándome en la cola de "ediciones sugeridas", observo un par de patrones de vez en cuando:

1. Gente que aprueba todo lo que se sugiere.
2. Gente que sugiere cambios que aportan poco valor.

Sobre el punto 1. hemos hablado en otros momentos y simplemente volveré a decir lo que [en otras ocasiones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1259/83): ¡No hay que sentirse mal por apretar el botón Omitir!

Sin embargo, centrándome en el punto 2, me he encontrado ya con dos casos de usuarios que pueblan la cola de revisión con pequeños cambios en publicaciones que necesitan muchos más. Se corrige alguna tilde, alguna [min/mayúscula](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16915/1674) y se deja la mayor parte sin hacer: formatos, gramática, etc.

En estos casos he rechazado la revisión con la opción:

> Esta edición no contribuye a que la publicación sea ni siquiera un poco más fácil de leer, más fácil de encontrar, más precisa o más accesible. Los cambios implementados son completamente superfluos o perjudican activamente la lectura.

Sin embargo, luego he visto que otros revisores han opinado que sí valía la pena y la han aceptado.

No es que esté en contra de estas ediciones, pues pueden ser válidas por parte de usuarios que pueden hacerlas sin que haya revisión de pares. Sin embargo, llenar la cola de revisión con sugerencias tan poco prácticas no me parece útil para el sitio.

He dejado algún comentario educado al revisor, indicándole que es bueno que revise, pero que consumir tiempo de los revisores para tan poca cosa es probablemente una pérdida de tiempo para todos. Por tanto, los emplazaba a realizar ediciones más sustanciales por el bien de todos: la calidad del sitio y el tiempo de cada revisor.

Visto que no tuve respuesta, en dos ocasiones he optado por hacer un reporte a los moderadores, que lo han marcado como útil y seguro que han dado buena cuenta de ello. Sin embargo, me surgen unas dudas:

- ¿Soy correcto usando el tiempo del moderador en un caso así? Como todos sabemos, solamente hay dos moderadores y estoy convencido que tienen muchísimo trabajo. No quiero darles más si hay algo que yo podría hacer. <sub>Ante el subsiguiente comentario que estaréis haciendoos (*¿y por qué no haces ese algo tú?*), quiero mencionar que el moderador tiene un plus de credibilidad que hace que pueda tener más efecto sobre un usuario que el que pude tener un usuario de a pie como yo.</sub>
- ¿Soy correcto intentando "educar" a los que sugieren mejoras? Seguro que más de uno pensará *¿pero a cuento de qué viene este usuario a decirme cómo hacer esto o aquello?*, pero no me pudo resistir a intentar que las contribuciones de cada cual tengan un impacto más útil en la página. ¿Qué tipo de texto "estándar" se podría escribir a estas personas?

Comment: Estoy convencido que sabes que tu comportamiento es correcto. Eres respetuoso y educado; estoy cierto que lo sabes. Te expresas de forma clara, sin faltas de ortografía, tu narración es coherente. **No necesitas que otros, _así sean moderadores_, validen tu buen comportamiento**.

Comment: @toledano gracias por tu comentario. Nótese que no es que quiera validar que esté haciendo algo bien para la comunidad, sino cuál es la mejor manera de hacerlo. Mi duda es si resulta práctico consumir "recursos" de moderador o si, por el contrario, me puedo "erigir" yo como persona a sugerir comportamientos a otros usuarios, sin que estos se lo tomen a mal.

Comment: Al ser más veterano [Spanish Language](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/) (5 años) vuestra experiencia como moderadores podría ser una (auto)respuesta interesante, fedorqui. Incluso aunque no toda la experiencia sea trasladable. ¿Cómo manejáis este tema allí?

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos por suerte o por desgracia, [spanish.se] es demasiado pequeño para estas casuísticas: tenemos unas 4 preguntas diarias y unos 10 elementos en la cola de revisión, por lo que una simple mirada a la pantalla principal da casi toda la información necesaria para moderar estas cosas. En mi año como moderador aún no me he encontrado con esta situación. Pero si me encuentro con ella, efectivamente agradezco mucho los reportes para ponerme en alerta. Comentario, chat privado, etc, serían los pasos a seguir.

Comment: Yo sinceramente si hay alguna mejora ortográfica (aunque "sólo" sea poner mayúsculas o tildes donde corresponde), de formateo del código suelo aceptarla o reetiquetado coherente. Tiene que haber fallos muy gordos para que además mejore la edición. Si alguien edita y mejora un poco ya es algo menos que hay que mejorar y se hace sobre una mejor base. No hace falta que esté perfecto a la primera.

Comment: Buena observación la de @Awes0meM4n.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ¿Soy correcto usando el tiempo del moderador en un caso así?

Estas en lo correcto y se agradece.

> Soy correcto intentando "educar" a los que sugieren mejoras?

Sin duda alguna es correcto intentar ayudar a los usuarios a utilizar el sitio.

> ¿Qué tipo de texto "estándar" se podría escribir a estas personas?

Siempre depende del caso pero recomiendo algo de este estilo:

> Hola @NombreDeUsuario, la edición que has propuesto no contiene todos los detalles necesarios para considerarlo una edición de calidad. Para futuras ediciones es importante corregir **todo** lo que sea mejorable para que la pregunta/respuesta tenga mas calidad.

Y luego has puesto en un comentario:

> entonces, ¿qué recomendáis? ¿Escribir un comentario al usuario y, si no funciona, reportároslo? ¿Reportároslo directamente?

Ambas.

Cuando analizamos los reportes normalmente lo primero es dejar un comentario y ver la evolución, si ya se ha dejado ese comentario y no hay cambios se puede pasar directamente a la acción (ban temporal incremental).

Edit: Sí, es respuesta oficial de los moderadores.

Comment: Gracias Miquel por ofrecer la respuesta por parte de los moderadores. Lo tendré en cuenta en el futuro, ¡gracias por vuestra labor!

Comment: Miquel: Sería bueno que aclararas si la respuesta es a nombre de los moderadores o a título personal. (estoy siendo conciso)

Comment: @Rubén sí, ha sido consensuado. Gracias!

Comment: Gracias doblemente a ambos, por responder y por su labor.

Answer (score 5):

> ¿Soy correcto usando el tiempo del moderador en un caso así?

**Si**

> ¿Soy correcto intentando "educar" a los que sugieren mejoras?

**Si**

> ¿Qué tipo de texto "estándar" se podría escribir a estas personas?

No existe un estándar, puedes crearlo, copiarlo o adaptarlo. O no poner ninguno.

Comment: +1 en ser conciso y correcto. Como bien indica toledano en su comentario si el objetivo de hacer cualquier cosa es bueno eso es indicativo de que vas por el buen camindo.

Comment: @MiquelColl pero entonces, ¿qué recomendáis? ¿Escribir un comentario al usuario y, si no funciona, reportároslo? ¿Reportároslo directamente?

Answer (score 5):

> ¿Soy correcto usando el tiempo del moderador en un caso así?

**Sí**

- No sólo es algo correcto si no es ejemplar. En mi opinión, los miembros de SOes no deberíamos preocuparnos por cuanto trabajo tienen los moderadores diamantados, si fuera demasiado, pues que se agreguen más, ya sea moderadores pro-tempore, o bien, por excepción, empleados de SO que hablen español o que sean muy buenos "usando" un traductor, ya sea artificial o humano.

> ¿Soy correcto intentando "educar" a los que sugieren mejoras?

**Sí**

- No sólo eres correcto sino que es una conducta ejemplar, en particular, considerando los 4 años de experiencia que tienes participando en el sitio en inglés y reputación y medallas que has obtenido en dicho sitio.

> ¿Qué tipo de texto "estándar" se podría escribir a estas personas?

Pendiente.

Comment: Gracias, Rubén. Me gusta especialmente lo de _los miembros de SOes no deberíamos preocuparnos por cuanto trabajo tienen los moderadores diamantados, si fuera demasiado, pues que se agreguen más_.